# Add owner name in AWS S3 grantee list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My owner name is canonical id and I don't have this in grantee list.

I tried to set this from AWS support forum   https://forums.aws.amazon.com/username.jspa but no use

[image]

So my question is how can I add my owner name in grantee list?
Or I have made mistake / skipped any step while creating S3 account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the AWS Console view you displayed, your owner name is simply displayed as "me".

Your "owner" is also not listed in the console view for your objects, which can make it confusing to know if you own an object (or know if you even have an ACL to access it) in your bucket or not.

From the AWS CLI, if you were to list your buckets or your objects. For example, in us-east-1 you would be able to see your owner name.

But, some you will find some other regions (including many newer regions) such as eu-central-1 don't support owner names.

Note: Not all AWS Regions support "Owner Names" and you should avoid relying on them. Instead it is recommended that you utilize canonical IDs where possible.

us-east-2 example:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --region us-east-2
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "myownername",
        "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
"Buckets": [
...
```

eu-central-1 example, note the missing "DisplayName" in the response:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --region eu-central-1
{
    "Owner": {
        "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
"Buckets": [
...
```

For regions which support owner names, you can see your owner name listed with a AWS CLI List:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket mybucket
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "LastModified": "2015-07-05T02:52:55.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"de901728bdc08050ee751e5cd9390e24\"",
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Key": "test.csv",
            "Owner": {
                "DisplayName": "myownername",
                "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "Size": 9767
        },
...
```

You can also see owners (in regions which support them) for ACL entries as shown below.

```
aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket mybucket --key mykey
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "myownername",
        "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "Type": "CanonicalUser",
                "DisplayName": "myownername",
                "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "Type": "Group",
                "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
            },
            "Permission": "READ"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If my owner name is "me" then why it is only displayed in list view? And as far as I know s3 is not region specific or it is?

Comment: In the console your owner name is only referenced in that menu as "me", your actual owner name is not shown.

Comment: You are right **"Not all AWS Regions support Owner Names"** I have changed my region from Mumbai to Singapore and owner name is added my list

Comment: Thank you and I would really appreciate if you provide list of AWS regions which doesn't support owner names or any useful link

Comment: I will have to check which ones do by testing each one, but I can tell you that no new regions have supported owner names in quite some time. So their usage is kind of in a deprecated state. I say deprecated because you can not use owner names reliably in all regions and this is especially true for all new regions as of a few years ago. There doesn't appear to have been any official deprecation.

Comment: Glad to help! Have a great day! :-)

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaBriefman, but do you have any reference to S3 documentation which tells that owner names are not supported in newer regions?